# Spring read query concurrent executinon in multiple threads

Tags: spring, jpa, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I Have a Spring boot project where I would like to execute a specific query in a database from x different threads while preventing different threads from reading the same database entries. So far I was able to run the query in multiple threads but had no luck on finding a way to "split" the read load. My code so far is as follows:

```
@Async
@Transactional
public CompletableFuture<Book> scanDatabase() {
    final List<Book> books = booksRepository.findAllBooks();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(books);
}
```

Any ideas on how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that.

1. If you have a numeric field in the data that is somewhat random you can add a condition to your where clause like `... and some_value % :N = :i` with `:N` being a parameter for the number of threads and `:i` being the index of the specific thread (0 based).
2. If you don't have a numeric field you can create one by using a hash function and apply it on some other field in order to turn it into something numeric. See your database specific documentation for available hash functions.
3. You could use an analytic function like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/row_number-analytic-function) to create a numeric value to be use in the condition.
4. You could query the number of rows in a first query and then query a the right [`Slice` using Spring Datas pagination feature](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/pagination-returning-slice.html).

And many more variants.
They all have in common that the complete set of rows must not change during the processing, otherwise you may get rows queried multiple times or not at all.

If you can't guarantee that you need to mark the records to be processed by a thread before actually selecting them, for example by marking them in an extra field or by using a `FOR UPDATE` clause in your query.

And finally there is the question if this is really what you need.
Querying the data in multiple threads probably doesn't make the querying part faster since it makes the query more complex and doesn't speed up those parts that typically limit the throughput: network between application and database and I/O in the database.

So it might be a better approach to select the data with one query and iterate through it, passing it on to a pool of thread for processing.

You also might want to take a look at Spring Batch which might be helpful with processing large amounts of data.